# Button position on the Right Top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to move refresh and Build button on the right top. The currently it stays on the right top.

I also added the following css, but it looks weird.

```
#refresh,#build
{
    line-height: 12px;
     width: 18px;
     font-size: 8pt;
     font-family: tahoma;
     margin-top: 1px;
     margin-right: 2px;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     right:0;
}

<div class="accordion-expand-holder">
<button type="button" id="refresh">Refresh</button>
<button type="button" id="build">Build</button>
<button type="button" class="open">Expand all</button>
<button type="button" class="close">Collapse all</button>
<div id="accordion">
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can simply float them right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add:

```
#refresh, #build{float:right}
```

to your css, it makes the #build, #refresh classes, to float right.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pojomx. How could I add a space between build and refresh buttons

Comment: margin-left:10dp or something like that

Answer (score 1):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/47/

```
#refresh, #build {
    float:right;
}
```